# How to sum a value in a grouped set of results? SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sum

So i need to sum the value "amount" where where debit_id and transfer_id are equals:
Table Example:

### debit_id | transfer_id | amount | debit_type

### 1184685  |    861288   |  25.5  |     2

### 1184685  |    861288   |  59.5  |     2

### 1168516  |    861288   |   23   |     0

Right now i use this query thaht gives me almost the expected values

```
    WITH ct AS
  ( SELECT *,rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY debit_id, transfer_id
   ORDER BY id DESC)
    FROM transfer_debits
  )
SELECT debit_id, transfer_id, amount, debit_type
FROM ct
WHERE rn = 1 AND transfer_id = 861288
ORDER BY debit_id, transfer_id;
```

I need this result but with the sum of the field amount grouped by debit_id and transfer_id
Desired result should be:

### debit_id | transfer_id | amount | debit_type

### 1184685  |    861288   |   85   |     2

### 1168516  |    861288   |   23   |     0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
Select debit_id, transfer_id, sum(amount) as "Amount_Sum"
from Transfer_debits
where transfer_id = 861288
group by  debit_id, transfer_id
```

For the debit_type, if you want a different sum depending on its value, just add it to the select and the group by.

Comment: Is there a way to use this query but adding another column in the select statement without adding it to the Group By Clause

Comment: sure, but you'll need to have it in a "max", "min", "sum" etc, function as it will not be group by this row. (let's say your agregation by debit_id and Tranfer_id returns 2 different debit_type... SQL cannot show both values in the same line)

Comment: Okay i already tried it and it does what i need, thank you very much sir